# How do I create/fix these methods?

Tags: java, class, methods, user-input

This is my assignment and I have a pretty good idea of what to do but I seem to be getting errors and I don't know how to fix them.

> “There is a famous story about a primary school teacher who wanted to
>   occupy his students’ time by making the children compute the sum of 1
>   + 2 + 3 + ... + 100 by hand. As the story goes, the teacher was astounded when one of the children immediately produced the correct
>   answer: 5050. The student, a child prodigy, was Carl Gauss, who grew
>   up to be one of the most famous mathematicians of the eighteenth
>   century. Repeat Gauss’s remarkable calculation by writing a loop that
>   will compute and print the above sum. After you have the program
>   working, rewrite it so you can compute 1 + 2 + ... + n where n is any
>   positive integer.”
>
> You should have a minimum of three methods
>
> Method **welcome** this method takes no parameter, and dose not return
>   back any value, it just salutes the user and prompts for an integer
>   value.
>
> Method **getVal** accepts an integer from the user and returns it back
>   to the main method
>
> Method **isValid** checks if the value entered by the user is greater
>   than zero, takes an integer parameter and returns back a Boolean value
>
> Your main should consist of, variable declarations as needed, function
>   calls, and the conditional operators as needed based on the methods
>   described above.

Here is what I have so far. I have two classes opened. One called methods for where I wrote all my methods. and One called methodslab which is where I call the methods to use them.

```
import java.util.*;
public class methods {
    static int intVal;

public static void welcome() {
    //greet user & prompt user for int vale
    System.out.println("Welcome.");
    System.out.println("Enter an integer value.");
}

public static int getVal() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    //accept integer from user
    intVal = input.nextInt();
    return intVal;
}

public static boolean isValid() {
    final boolean validation;
    if (intVal < 0) {
        validation = false;
        methods.getVal();
    }
    else
        validation = true;
    return validation;

}
}
```

and....

```
public class methodslab {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    //call methods
    methods.welcome();
    methods.getVal(int num);
    methods.isValid();
    //declare variables
    final int end_value = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    while (num > end_value) //test
    {
        sum = sum + num; //adding nums from user input to 0
        num--; //update
    }
    //display sum
    System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
}
}
```

the errors i get are for the class called methodsLab

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Syntax error on token "int", delete this token
methodslab.java /labs/src/labs  line 7  Java Problem

num cannot be resolved to a variable
methodslab.java /labs/src/labs  line 7  Java Problem

num cannot be resolved to a variable
methodslab.java /labs/src/labs  line 12 Java Problem

num cannot be resolved to a variable
methodslab.java /labs/src/labs  line 14 Java Problem

num cannot be resolved to a variable
methodslab.java /labs/src/labs  line 15 Java Problem

Comment: What errors are you getting, then?  Be sure to include the relevant details in the question you're asking.

Comment: i edited my question so it shows the errors at the bottom. sorry i'm new to this website so i'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: `methods.getVal(int num);` makes no sense to me, change it to `methods.getVal(num);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all: I don't see that "ask for another number" is part of the assignment for the "isValud" method.

And as the error message tells you, you did not declare your "num" variable, but are trying to use it.

Here you declare sum, you can (and have to) do the same for "num":

```
 int sum = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

in the class methodlabs, declare the (int num) variable **BEFORE** using it in the method GetVal().
and anyway, the method GetVal() isn't requiring any parameter to be executed, so maybe you should use it like this:

> int num = GetVal();